# Reading specific values in hash of hashes - Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have an hash of hash map as below. Please note that the hash map is very huge which contains PluginsStatus as Success or Error. When PluginsStatus for a key is Success then I need not process anything (I have handled this scenario) but if its Error I need to to display in the order  - `PluginsStatus`, `PluginspatchLogName`, `PluginsLogFileName_0`, `PluginsLogFileLink_0`, `PluginsLogFileErrors_0` and so on.

Please note, I do not know exactly how many keys (in hash of a hash) i.e.  `PluginsLogFileName`, `PluginsLogFileLink`, `PluginsLogFileErrors` exists i.e. it is dynamic.

```
 $VAR1 = {          'Applying Template Changes' => {
                            'PluginsLogFileErrors_2' => 'No Errors',
                            'PluginsStatus' => 'Error',
                            'PluginsLogFileName_1' => 'Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileName_2' => 'ApplyingTemplates.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileErrors_1' => 'ERROR: FAPSDKEX-00024 : Error in undeploying  template.Cause : Unknown.Action : refer to log file for more details.',
                            'PluginspatchLogName' => '2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileLink_0' => '/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileName_0' => '2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileErrors_0' => 'No Errors',
                            'PluginsLogFileLink_2' => 'configlogs/ApplyingTemplates.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileLink_1' => 'configlogs/Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log'
                           },
                'Configuring Keystore Service' => {
                            'PluginsStatus' => 'Error',
                            'PluginsLogFileName_1' => 'Configuring_Keystore_Service_2015-05-11_11-11-37PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileErrors_1' => 'ERROR: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.',
                            'PluginspatchLogName' => '2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileLink_0' => '/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileName_0' => '2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                            'PluginsLogFileErrors_0' => 'No Errors',
                            'PluginsLogFileLink_1' => 'configlogs/Configuring_Keystore_Service_2015-05-11_11-11-37PM.log'
                           },
                'Applying Main Configuration' => {
                           'PluginsStatus' => 'Error',
                           'PluginspatchLogName' => '2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                           'PluginsLogFileName_0' => 'Applying_Main_Configuration_2015-05-12_01-11-21AM.log',
                           'PluginsLogFileLink_0' => '/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                           'PluginsLogFileErrors_0' => 'ERROR: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.apps.ad.common.exception.ADException: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.... 104 lines more'
                           }
        };
```

Below is an output snippet I am looking for:

```
Plugin name is = Applying Template Changes
PluginsStatus = Error
PluginspatchLogName = 2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log
PluginsLogFileName_0 = 2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log
PluginsLogFileLink_0 = /tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log
PluginsLogFileErrors_0 = No Errors
PluginsLogFileName_1 = Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log
PluginsLogFileLink_1 = configlogs/Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-       57-40AM.log
PluginsLogFileErrors_1 = ERROR: FAPSDKEX-00024 : Error in undeploying  template.Cause : Unknown.Action : refer to log file for more details.,
PluginsLogFileName_2 = ApplyingTemplates.log
PluginsLogFileLink_2 = configlogs/ApplyingTemplates.log
PluginsLogFileErrors_2 = No Errors`
```

Please let me know if someone could help me here ?

Comment: Why are you building this hash, when you could just read directly from the XML object you're parsing?

Comment: @Sobrique - Extremely sorry for bringing up with this question. You are absolutely right. I modified my code as per your suggestion. Thank you again for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You have built a hash that is less than ideal for your purposes. You should create a `LogFile` hash element that has an array as its value. After that the process is trivial

```
{
  "Applying Main Configuration" => {
    LogFile => [
      {
        Errors => "ERROR: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.apps.ad.common.exception.ADException: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.... 104 lines more",
        Link   => "/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
        Name   => "Applying_Main_Configuration_2015-05-12_01-11-21AM.log",
      },
    ],
    patchLogName => "2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
    Status => "Error",
  },
  "Applying Template Changes" => {
    LogFile => [
      {
        Errors => "No Errors",
        Link   => "/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
        Name   => "2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
      },
      {
        Errors => "ERROR: FAPSDKEX-00024 : Error in undeploying  template.Cause : Unknown.Action : refer to log file for more details.",
        Link   => "configlogs/Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log",
        Name   => "Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log",
      },
      {
        Errors => "No Errors",
        Link   => "configlogs/ApplyingTemplates.log",
        Name   => "ApplyingTemplates.log",
      },
    ],
    patchLogName => "2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
    Status => "Error",
  },
  "Configuring Keystore Service" => {
    LogFile => [
      {
        Errors => "No Errors",
        Link   => "/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
        Name   => "2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
      },
      {
        Errors => "ERROR: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.",
        Link   => "configlogs/Configuring_Keystore_Service_2015-05-11_11-11-37PM.log",
        Name   => "Configuring_Keystore_Service_2015-05-11_11-11-37PM.log",
      },
    ],
    patchLogName => "2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log",
    Status => "Error",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the `keys` of the hash. Use the `$hash{key}{inner_key}` syntax to get into the nested hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %error = ( 'Applying Template Changes' => {
                  'PluginsLogFileErrors_2' => 'No Errors',
                  'PluginsStatus' => 'Error',
                  'PluginsLogFileName_1' => 'Applying_Template_Changes_2015-05-12_02-57-40AM.log',
                   # ...
                  'PluginsLogFileLink_0' => '/tmp/xpath/2015-05-11_08-14-28PM.log',
                  'PluginsLogFileErrors_0' => 'ERROR: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.apps.ad.common.exception.ADException: Failed to query taxonomy attribute AllProductFamilyAndDomains.... 104 lines more',
              },
);
for my $step (keys %error) {
    print "Plugin name is = $step\n";
    for my $detail (sort keys %{ $error{$step} }) {
        print "$detail = $error{$step}{$detail}\n";
    }
}
```